# Why is my WCF method requiring parameters that aren't defined?

Tags: c#, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [*Result and *ResultSpecified parameters in WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403126/result-and-resultspecified-parameters-in-wcf-service)

In the interface I define the IsAuthorized method as:

```
[OperationContract]
bool IsAuthorized(string userId);
```

The Implementation is defined as:

```
public bool IsAuthorized(string userId)
{
    User user = new User(userId);
    return user.Authorized;
}
```

When I try to try to invoke the method I get an error:

```
No overload for method 'IsAuthorized' takes 1 arguments
```

When I mouse over the method, intellisense shows the following structure:

```
Void ReportingService.IsAuthorized(string userId, out bool IsAuthorizedResult, 
      out bool IsAuthorizedResultSpecified)
```

To my knowledge I haven't changed any settings in the wcf, this was the default project that came up from vs2010, and I just added this method.

**Why is my method being changed? Or how do I get it to return a bool, rather than having to use a bool out?**

---

From the answer and comments from [*Result and *ResultSpecified parameters in WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403126/result-and-resultspecified-parameters-in-wcf-service).

I needed to remove the service as a `Web` reference, and re-add it as a `Service` reference.

Comment: Are you trying to overload the IsAuthorized() method?